# RC Snubber connection

Tags: ac, dimmer, snubber

I'm going to use this [AC Dimmer Module](https://robotdyn.com/ac-light-dimmer-module-1-channel-3-3v-5v-logic-ac-50-60hz-220v-110v.html) with an inductive load, so I plan to help it by adding an [RC Snubber Module](https://arduino-shop.eu/arduino-platform/1648-rc-snubber-for-switching-inductive-loads.html). Most of the schemes show that the best way to use an RC snubber is to connect it across the TRIAC terminals (**Option 1**), but what if I connect it to the module terminals (**Option 2**)... will it operate properly?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't really make a difference if you connect the snubber with wires. Connecting a component a short way is all about the unwanted inductivity created by the area enclosed by the wires. So they only "correct" way is to use SMD components and to add the snubber on the board itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- option 1 across the Triac is to filter egress or outgoing EMI transients when the Triac turns off to high impedance from inductive Flyback but goes thru the load
- option 2 across the grid is very low impedance except at RF so the snubber is more for line RF grid noise that might false trigger the gate if too sensitive. However it also suppresses some egress impulses with R while C charges but has less effect to suppress possible over-voltage spikes across the Off transition of the Triac.  A individual specific load and values must be examined on a case by case situation. You might need both in some cases. But the Q must be low and interactions between both must be analyzed with simulations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply!

Comment: Welcome.I’m fed up with my fat finger problems and IOS and auto in corrections

Answer (score 1):

Snubber across the triac is best for stopping triac switching noise affecting radio reception .Hence this approach is the most common .This does mean that some AC current flows even when the triac dimmer is turned off .This current is not lethal with normal snubber caps .Some Led lamps will glow in the dark and other Led lamps will flash with these currents .Snubbing the output as well as the triac cures this .